# Is it possible to budle Unity application, transfer it to the device and run it in some kind of player?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

It may be a silly question, but I dont know what to google.

Consider this, we are building unity AR application that run on IOS. Every client has custom need, so there is custom application for every one of them. Because of that whole application lifecycle managment is nigthmare.

**We would like to build just one appliaction as player and download all content (unity app) from server and just run it.**

Is something like that possible? How can we achieve that?

Comment: Can you give one or more examples of "Custom need"?

Comment: Different logic, not just model and assets.

Comment: Look into AssetBundle

Comment: AssetBundle looks promising, thanks for tip. I will look into that and let you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) recommended by @Everts seems like good fit, it does not solve everything but for sure helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variable that can be selected to set up the application based on that one global variable.

For example make a class called "Global" as a Singleton class, then call that class from wherever you need custom needs set up to see in which way they should be adjusted.

If it's not only IOS related, you can use Platform Dependent Compilation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: We need the possibility to deploy and update apps on the go. Not pushing new version to store. Or I am worng that this idea is to have multi app with selector on top.

Comment: Well, depending how they need to be updated, you might be able to use Remote Settings:
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/06/02/introducing-remote-settings-update-your-game-in-an-instant/

Otherwise I think you have to upload apps to the app store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html